# Xcode 8 constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, constraints

I was coding in swift on the latest version of Xcode (as of 12/1/17). Since I'm new to coding in swift, I was unable to figure out a way to make my app compatible for all screen sizes. While building the app, my "View as" was set as iPhone SE. Now when I try running the program in another screen size, the size of the buttons, textfields and labels aren't in proportion. I found others with the same problem but none were able to answer my problem in a manner that I'd understand. [This is one of the many frames on my storyboard that seems to be having the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOQLC.png)
I tried to click on the "Reset to suggested constraints" button but that only seemed to mess up the screen. It would be helpful if you'd be able to help me with this specific frame.

Comment: To work in all screens sizes use Any-Any size class and set constraints.

Comment: It is hard to find out your exact problem but i recommend you to watch some tutorials about auto layouts.

Comment: Avijit Nagare I couldn't find the option for Any-Any size class in Xcode 8.1. would you be able to guide me on where I can find some tutorials relating to it? (coz most youtube tutorials I found made close to no sense to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I have run into layout problems, I always find it easiest to delete them all, and start again.  If you leave some in place, and start trying to fix others it can be very hard to tell what's going on.

The key thing with constraints is to keep it simple.  If you only have 6 labels which are all in one column, then you can set the constraints for the first one (Displacement) in your example - make sure you're happy with the positioning, and then align all of the others to have the same leading edge, and give them Top & Bottom space constraints .  This means if you decide to move them all out from the edge, you only have to change one.

Comment: do I make the Top and Bottom space constraints relative to neighbouring Labels or to the margins?

Comment: To the neighbouring controls - that way if you move the top one, the rest move with it and you only have to make one change.  If you have a group of controls which you want to stay together, always set up theirs constraints relative to each other

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 8 provide efficient way to use autolayout.

You can check the video also. This works for me fine.

https://youtu.be/lx1NRHRMwUg